# Export data to excel from vue2

Tags: excel, vue.js, vuejs2, xlsx

I have an app built in Vue2 and I need to export data to excel, displaying a result like the image you find below.

I have gone through several vue libraries, but I have not found something that allow me to create a layout like that.

The only one seems this one: https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export but it's for React.

Can somebody point me out a vue or js library che does the job?

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) might be a good solution to your problem. It's not specific to Vue 2, but it does allow you to have control over which cells you write to.

[SO question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441138/how-to-write-into-a-particular-cell-using-xlsx-npm-package)